# Keep input value after reloading/refreshing page

Tags: jquery, html, input

I can set a value in input like this:

```
$("#Text").click(function () {
var value = $(this).html();
$("input").val(value);
});
```

The problem is that I need the inputted value to be there after a reload/refresh. I have Googled for this but all I can find are php solutions or very difficult cookie settings. I'm hoping for a simple Jquery snippet. Something I understand because I have to do many more events/functions with this and they are all Jquery based.

Answer (score 1):

Store the value in hidden variable and retrieve it from the same this might help

Comment: The value changes on every click and then(second) the page gets reloaded so the var will be blank Im affraid..

Comment: otherwise u can go for query string u can take the value from query string

Comment: Wouldn't a reload 'reset' the string to its default? I mean you can manipulate but on refresh the data will get lost.

Comment: hm... Cookies might be a optimal solution